# Powershell - Output string to CSV and format

Tags: powershell, csv, formatting, output

I've given a simple example below. Does anyone know what I have to do to output the string into two columns? My searching has not returned much in the way of formatting outputs into CSV. Please point me in the right direction!

```
$LogFile = c:\somefile.csv
"Hello World" | Out-File $LogFile
```

Comment: Add ``;`` instead of space.

Comment: Thanks for replying. It doesn't work for me. I also tried separating into different "" as well as the same.

Comment: You need to explain where the columns are coming from. e.g. In your example would each word be in its own column?

Comment: Hi there, sorry for the unsuitable example. Basically I will have two variables, both strings that need inserting into separate columns in a CSV file. So $A in one column and $B in another. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading your comments which supplement your question, creating a `PSObject` around the variables you are trying to export to CSV might give you more control over your output. Consider the following:

```
$A = "Hello";
$B = "World";

$wrapper = New-Object PSObject -Property @{ FirstColumn = $A; SecondColumn = $B }
Export-Csv -InputObject $wrapper -Path C:\temp\myoutput.txt -NoTypeInformation
```

Creates the file `C:\temp\myoutput.txt` with two columns (`FirstColumn` and `SecondColumn`) and the variables `$A` and `$B` placed in those columns in the first row

Comment: Hi, that's great! Tell me one more thing if you know. How is the column order decided? I changed column one to "File" and column two to "Result", but column two appears first?

Comment: Unfortunately the order of a Powershell hashtable (which is what you are passing to the `-Property` argument) is not guaranteed, so you can't control the order of the properties on the `PSObject`. If you don't mind it getting ugly, you can work around it by doing `-InputObject ($wrapper | select File, Result)`.

Comment: Its no real problem. Your answer still suits my purpose. Thanks for your help and the extra info! :)

Comment: Good stuff and no problem :-)

Comment: You can control the column order:  $wrapper | Select-Object FirstColumn, SecondColumn | Export-CSV C:\temp\myoutput.txt -NoTypeInfo

Comment: Export-Csv  doesn't do the correct thing  if the string has a new  line (`n) in it. $A = "Hello`n Testing";
$B = "World,DoDa"; comes out as "FirstColumn","SecondColumn"
"Hello
 Testing","World,DoDa"

Answer (score 3):

To be honest with you I think your example is probably too trivial. For the example that you have though:

```
'Hello World'.Replace(' ',',') | Out-File $LogFile
```

This will of course give a faulty result if there are spaces that you want to keep in the data. Hence my expectation that your example is too trivial.

Comment: Have to say I like this method better. Yes it takes a bit more thought upfront on how your file will look but gives you so much more freedom!