# Turn a string into a csv Powershell

Tags: string, csv, powershell

I have a variable that will be put into powershell as a string from a different program that uses powershell. Lets say the variable is `"value1, value2, value3"` in it's entirety. I want to save this as a csv file.

I've tried using `export-csv` but the output I get is

```
#TYPE System.String
Length
34
```

Is there a way I can use powershell to turn the value of the string into a csv or do I have to separate each item?

Comment: So you have on variable which is a string? "value1, value2, value3"? Also, show us how you want your csv to look like.

Comment: Show us the code you use to export your data to CSV. This is probably because a string object only contains one property which is `Length`.

Comment: @David he's using Export-Csv.

Comment: @Chris Kuperstein, Yes ofc, but when and how he is using `Export-Csv` is another question.

Answer (score 3):

```
$string = ("value1, value2, value3").Split(',').Replace(" ","")

[PSCustomObject]@{
    'Column1'=$string[0]
    'Column2'=$string[1]
    'Column3'=$string[2]
} | Export-Csv .\file.csv -Append -Force -NoTypeInformation
Invoke-Item .\file.csv
```

You haven't said anything about what your columns are named, what type of information you're exporting and how you want it formatted. I worked with what you provided and that's it.

The answer to your question is also easily found in google.

[Powershell - Output string to CSV and format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28590074/powershell-output-string-to-csv-and-format)

Comment: If there was an answer on SO that fit the bill then flagging a dupe should suffice. If you would argue this question is different I would suggest it is vague and should not have been answered. Some people frown on answering duplicate questions.